# Value in textbox is always the same on update statement

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I select values from database into textboxes on page load. Then when I change them and want to update the database, values are same as original values. For example I select name *Robin Hood* into TextBoxName, change it to *Bill Gates*, but the value of textbox on updating is still *Robin Hood*. How can I fix this behavior?

However this applies only to textboxes with `TextMode="SingleLIne"` Or `"MultiLine`". When textbox has `TextMode="Url"` for example, it works fine.

```vb
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
 'Bind
    Try
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Profiles WHERE (ProfileId = @ProfileId)"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfileId", Request.QueryString("id"))
            conn.Open()
            Dim rd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While rd.Read()
                ProfileImage.ImageUrl = rd.Item("ProPicUrl")
                txtName.Text = rd.Item("Name")
                txtCity.Text = rd.Item("City")
                drpRegion.Items.FindByText(rd.Item("Region")).Selected = True
                txtAge.Text = rd.Item("Age")
                RadioButtonList1.Items.FindByText(rd.Item("Sex")).Selected = True
                txtLink.Text = rd.Item("Link")
                txtPhone.Text = rd.Item("Phone")
                txtAbout.Text = rd.Item("About")
                txtMotto.Text = rd.Item("Motto")
                txtGoal.Text = rd.Item("Goal")
                txtHobby.Text = rd.Item("Hobby")
            End While
            conn.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim fileUrl As String = "~/ProPics/"
    Dim name As String = txtName.Text
    Try
        'Save profile picture
        Try
            If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
                fileUrl += FileUpload1.FileName
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(fileUrl))
            Else
                fileUrl = ProfileImage.ImageUrl
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            UploadMessage.Text = "Nastala chyba při nahrávání obrázku." + vbCrLf + "Chybové hlášení: " + ex.Message
        End Try

        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Profiles SET Name = @Name, ProPicUrl = @Url, City = @City, Region = @Region, Age = @Age, Sex = @Sex, Link = @Link, Phone = @Phone, About = @About, Motto = @Motto, Goal = @Goal, Hobby = @Hobby WHERE (ProfileId = @ProfileId)"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Url", fileUrl)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Region", drpRegion.SelectedItem.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txtAge.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Link", txtLink.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@About", txtAbout.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Motto", txtMotto.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Goal", txtGoal.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hobby", txtHobby.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfileId", Request.QueryString("id"))
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()
            'Refresh page
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a check for [IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) property of the page when you execute code in the Page_Load event.

```vb
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    if Not PostBack Then

       ...... code to execute only the first time the Page_Load is called

       Try


       End Try
       Catch ex As Exception

       End Try
    End If 

    .. code to execute every time....

End Sub
```

When your user clicks on a button with `Runat=Server` then the button calls the event on the server side code, but this cause a new call to Page_Load.

Actually your code reloads from the database the original value everytime the Page_Load event executes and thus your button click event code sees the original value from the database instead of the modified value.

This article on the [Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) could be useful here

Comment: Thanks for answer, I should have tought about this.